# Rename all Git branch names to lowercase on Windows (GitHub remote)

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, case-sensitive

Our team is using Git for Windows and Git Extensions with GitHub as the remote repository. People have created branches with inconsistent capitalisation, which has caused some problems when two people have different names (differing only by case) for the same branch.

We'd like to standardise on using lowercase for all branch names to avoid this problem, but how do we convert all existing branch names to lowercase? There are many branches, both local and remote and some have pull requests outstanding. I only really care about "active" branches, i.e. those from which people will push again.

I tried the steps listed on https://gist.github.com/lttlrck/9628955, but ran into some problems. First, I can't rename "BranchName" directly to "branchname" in Windows, but OK, this can be worked around with a temporary name.

The more serious issue is that we have "folder names" in branches, e.g. "Test/RenameTest". When I rename the local branch to "test/renametest" it appears to work, but then pushing it fails with `fatal: test/renametest cannot be resolved to branch.` I think this is because I have other branches named "Test/Whatever", so the "folder name" is still "Test", not "test". Having to manually rename every branch ever checked out on every machine is a daunting prospect. I'm hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't delete all the inactive branches?

Comment: We could - they're not the problem. All the active branches are the problem.

Comment: Oh okay. The "Having to manually rename every branch ever checked out on every machine" made it sound like the inactive branches were being included.

Comment: Actually, I suppose the inactive branches are a problem in the sense that they set the folder name under the .git/refs directory. So if somebody has checked out "Test/One" (inactive), it will still cause problems when they try to rename and push "Test/Two" (active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a remote branch based on another remote branch in one step:

```
git push origin origin/PATH/TO/MY_BRANCH:refs/heads/path/to/my_branch
```

Note the syntax:

```
git push [remote] [REF]:refs/heads/[BRANCH]
```

And since `origin/PATH/TO/MY_BRANCH` is a valid ref, it can be used for the `git push` command.

Then just delete the incorrectly named remote branch, like so:

```
git push --delete origin PATH/TO/MY_BRANCH
```

If your Windows Git Bash terminal has `grep` and `sed` and `cut` commands available you can probably do it all at once.  Start with something like this, and once it looks good, pipe its output into its own shell script (e.g., `sh script_below.sh > my_big_git_rename.sh`), and then run that!

```sh
#!/bin/sh
git branch --remotes   | # list all remote branches
grep '[A-Z]'           | # only list branches with upper-case in their name
cut -b 10-             | # cut first 10 chars (assumes remote named 'origin')

# build "git push" command:
sed 's/\(^.*$\)/git push origin origin\/\1:refs\/heads\/\1/' | 

sed 's/:\(.*\)/:\L\1/'   # lower-case the branch name
```

Comment: OK, it seems to work in one working copy, e.g. I renamed "Test/RenameTest"->"test/renametest". However, when I try `git pull` in another working copy (which had the "Test/RenameTest" branch checked out) I get "Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/Test/RenameTest' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched." I don't understand where this is configured. I've tried renaming the local branch to lowercase using `git branch -m`. I've even tried manually setting "Default merge with" in the Git Extensions Remote repositories dialog, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Ahhh, after renaming the local branch, you need to also change the remote branch it's tracking:  git branch -m Test/RenameTest test/renametest; git branch --set-upstream-to origin/test/renametest

Comment: OK, so it appears that I really need 4 commands per branch to complete the rename:

`git push origin origin/OLD_BRANCH_NAME:refs/heads/NEW_BRANCH_NAME
;
git push --delete origin OLD_BRANCH_NAME
;
git branch -m OLD_BRANCH_NAME NEW_BRANCH_NAME
;
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/NEW_BRANCH_NAME NEW_BRANCH_NAME
;`

Comment: This seems to work - thanks again! Clarification after further testing: the commands to rename remote branches need to be run only once for the repository (so by one person), while the commands to rename local branches need to be run for each working copy (so by everyone).

Comment: Glad to hear things are working!   Yes, your final clarification is right.   I should probably update my answer...

Comment: @EM0: So did you finally use temporary name to convert a branch from UPPER to lower case OR you just did it in one go? I'm also in the same situation on Windows (Git Bash) trying to convert branches from UPPER to lower case.

Comment: I don't remember now, but what I do remember is that people had issues in renaming their local branches and one guy nearly lost a week's worth of work. If I was to do this again I would tell everyone to push all the code they want to keep, rename the remote branches and then have everyone re-clone the repository (keeping a backup of their local one just in case).